# Django manager is not accessible via instance

Tags: mysql, django

I have one MySQL table created using a class named `UserProfile` and another using a class named `Connection`. I have written the following code to retrieve each connections request sent by one user and turn the name of the target into a string:

```
allprofiles = UserProfile.objects.all()

for UserProfile in allprofiles:
    userconnections = Connection.objects.filter(source_user=UserProfile)
    for Connection in userconnections:
        toplay = Connection
        target_tostring = toplay.target_user
        print target_tostring
```

But when I try to run this, Django displays the following:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-323348f76c1f> in <module>()

      1 for UserProfile in allprofiles:
----> 2         userconnections = Connection.objects.filter(source_user=UserProfile)
      3         for Connection in userconnections:
      4                 toplay = Connection
      5                 target_tostring = toplay.target_user

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.pyc in __get__(self, instance, type)

    209     def __get__(self, instance, type=None):
    210         if instance != None:
--> 211             raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % type.__name__)
    212         return self.manager
    213 

AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Connection instances
```

What am I doing wrong? I have written similar code in the past without any problems.

Comment: What does your `UserProfile` and `Connection` models look like? Please edit your question and add the source code for those models.

Comment: Use UserProfile, the same name as model definition, for iteration is not a good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overriding your `UserProfile` and `Connection` classes. In other words, you're replacing the model classes with data from your database. Use the following instead:

```
for user_profile in UserProfile.objects.all():
    for user_connection in Connection.objects.filter(source_user=user_profile):
        print user_connection.target_usr
```